# DKIM failing but can't find any problem with hashing or signing syntax

Tags: node.js, email, cryptography, dkim, dmarc

I'm writing my own DKIM implementation in Node.js and I'm having a problem getting my DKIM to pass.

*Here is my mail body:*

dGVzdA==\r\n

*Here is the body hash (sha256):*

STFhz2ITzV8iSPWgLK0kfUa69jvk327MHRw2ZpGDvWE=

*Here is my dkim header hash input:*

from:test@test.test.org\r\ndkim-signature:v=1;a=rsa-sha256;c=relaxed;s=wo8vy2th;d=test.test.org;h=from;bh=STFhz2ITzV8iSPWgLK0kfUa69jvk327MHRw2ZpGDvWE=;b=

I then sign that using this code:

```
crypto.createSign('rsa-sha256').update(headerHash).sign({key: processItem.sharedData.dkim_private_key, passphrase: dkimDomainKeyPassphrase}, 'base64');
```

Yet on arrival I get dkim=fail. 
My DNS _domainkey does resolve correctly.

Note for this example I am only using the From: header just to try to find the problem. In reality I will be using all the recommended headers.

EDIT: here is the raw email source that is failing:

```
Delivered-To: wyatt5@ethereal.email
Return-Path: <test@test2.cybermancy.org>
Authentication-Results: mx.ethereal.email; spf=permerror smtp.mailfrom=test2.cybermancy.org; dkim=fail header.i=@test2.cybermancy.org
Received-SPF: PermError (mx.ethereal.email: domain of test2.cybermancy.org does not designate 67.205.181.191 as permitted sender) receiver=mx.ethereal.email; identity=mailfrom; client-ip=67.205.181.191; helo=mta.postagent.io; envelope-from=<test@test2.cybermancy.org>
Received-SPF: None (mx.ethereal.email: domain of mta.postagent.io does not designate 67.205.181.191 as permitted sender) receiver=mx.ethereal.email; identity=helo; client-ip=67.205.181.191; helo=mta.postagent.io; envelope-from=<test@test2.cybermancy.org>
Received: from mta.postagent.io ([67.205.181.191])
    by mx.ethereal.email (Haraka/2.8.23) with ESMTP id A08331BF-93B5-41C1-ADBA-B7B0F9DEF1CF.1
    envelope-from <test@test2.cybermancy.org>;
    Fri, 17 Jan 2020 14:18:12 +0100
Message-ID: <23e18f92-e6f3-4fab-bfa3-649584bec5b4+1579267090958@mta.postagent.io>
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed; s=wo8vy2th;        
    h=mime-version:from:to:date:subject;        
    d=test2.cybermancy.org;        
    bh=STFhz2ITzV8iSPWgLK0kfUa69jvk327MHRw2ZpGDvWE=;        
    b=RH/CNjqKlOcLEuwT8zCEo2k0UyDDAlCfsEVkPBU83pbNNDNxVMUVDQmHsxjPUw/GLm0osY948u1YhUIC8clAfUdaaVQqHfWXDmuk24t+uaeHLwQu/dTRuLJfFjO+lXlnx4VFNxQHj3kBAWJ6/aNhO5kq3QI7u7uGWtGf+4pZzg8=
To: wyatt5@ethereal.email
From: test@test2.cybermancy.org
Subject: test subject
Date: Fri, 17 Jan 2020 13:18:10 +0000
X-report-abuse: Please forward a copy of this message, including all headers, to abuse@test.org
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

dGVzdA==
```

Note: I have tried the signature value with folding and without. For this example I did not fold it.

Here is my header hash input:

```
mime-version:1.0\\r\\nfrom:test@test2.cybermancy.org\r\nto:wyatt5@ethereal.email\r\ndate:Fri, 17 Jan 2020 13:18:10 +0000\r\nsubject:test subject\r\ndkim-signature:v=1;a=rsa-sha256;c=relaxed;s=wo8vy2th;d=test2.cybermancy.org;h=mime-version:from:to:date:subject;bh=STFhz2ITzV8iSPWgLK0kfUa69jvk327MHRw2ZpGDvWE=;b=
```

DKIM selector: wo8vy2th
DKIM public key at wo8vy2th._domainkey.test2.cybermancy.org

```
k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC7V0yupUNowYt7ciprmmn3s2sQkQA8cI7LVywrTwAOAS1RMAAcPRGIO0By/XHlh8uTMf0Kw+GscrHRz90TUJpRdDx9lCKCwUE6taWVsdsgUPmpJ1AxHDCrmbadFdjsc0hNTCt8niNsmph8qiV/6T6Qjtt/4piVlxKxzLPIJn976QIDAQAB
```

EDIT 2:

Here is my private key as printed with JSON.stringify():

```
"-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----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\n67kB7QutXMLsv/S36UioBbg=\n-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

The encrypted private key's password is:

nkwsrcdk7gaah4vl7h0fdd1xjssefyibtyftyfjd98ewjmfnkisjt5t5jjjdfghgfdsrtyurtyu

Answer (score 0):

And you do have a  the public key of the signing key published in the DNS record:
wo8vy2th._domainkey.test.test.org ?

That requires you to have access to the test.org DNS zone.

DKIM signatures requires domain keys - That is the only way to verify signature.

did you read the RFC 6376? One thing is that CR+LF must be encoded. 
Look in 3.4.3 and see if an empty body gets the right sha-256: (for c=relaxed)

```
47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=
```

Try to recreate the hashes using an incoming DKIM verified mail as data input to validate your has calculations. SHould be trivial to test your hashing/relaxed/simple on known good mails. Say sent from gmail to yourself

Comment: [sonr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12707272/sonrh) has a body of "test", base64 encoded.  The body hash is correct.  However, with neither the signature nor the public key it is not possible to verify it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So I shouldn't have used test.org as my SO example I realize that now. I went ahead and put in the real domain you can use to test this yourself. So the body hash is correct in this post and I originally did verify it already exactly the way you describe. I've now included the entire email body including ESP headers, and my header hash input so you can calculate the signature yourself and find my error. Thanks again for responding!

Answer (score 0):

The signature `s` that you create with `crypto.createSign()` should immediately verify with:

```js
    crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA256').update(ch, 'binary').verify(pk, s, 'base64');
```

where `ch` is the canonicalized header, and pk your public key (adorned with `'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n'` and similar to have OpenSSL grok it).  I tried with the *header hash input* given above, with and without the double backslashes after the first header field.  I also tried with the canonicalized header obtained from the message above:

```js
    ch = 'mime-version:1.0\r\nfrom:test@test2.cybermancy.org\r\n' +
         'to:wyatt5@ethereal.email\r\n' +
         'date:Fri, 17 Jan 2020 13:18:10 +0000\r\nsubject:test subject\r\n' +
         'dkim-signature:v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed; s=wo8vy2th;' +
         ' h=mime-version:from:to:date:subject;' +
         ' d=test2.cybermancy.org;' +
         ' bh=STFhz2ITzV8iSPWgLK0kfUa69jvk327MHRw2ZpGDvWE=;' +
         ' b=';
```

In no case the signature was verified.  Hence, something is wrong in the data you supplied above.

You must closely follow the [canonicalization instructions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-3.4.2), so that signer and verifier obtain the same blob.

Comment: I've also tried it with only the from header (which i verified to be in the correct canonical format) and still it would not create a passing signature.  I also confirmed my private key is in the correct format like you mentioned. Do you have any other ideas for what could be going wrong? Did you check my DNS record? I updated the question to include my private key.

Comment: To add: I also did what you said with testing the verification right away and createVerify did return true on my signed value. Perhaps there is a syntax error in my sent DKIM header (not the content hashed?) or perhaps there is a DNS error?

Comment: The way I set my _domainkey's "p=" value was to generate a key with node's crypto generateKeyPair and I simply removed all instances of \n and removed the ----Text---- at the beginning and end.

Comment: @sonrh: given that the body hash is correct, the only reason why you verify while another verifier cannot is that you get a different canonicalized header.

Comment: When I sign with your key the above message, The signature I get using the above ch is `b=rRR28Zia+CI56/nSUumvhbb5mHAfThwTLPyt3omCrbce46NqG2Yx3/BjzBk45ZInyYOFeBVAwj8xgOWKne775nQFMWK5g8sauoWaw/3wQfImixIV6fMS9VbV5RaopCGJv6Bp7KQxIJ1zDe7idUDhBq3dDldKiWcCizhNMCu64DQ=`.  With that value the messages passes my stock DKIM verifier.  That proves that `ch` is correct and that your public key is perfectly readable from DNS.

Comment: Hey! I solved it. All this time tinkering with things and the problem was right in my face. I was hashing the header before signing it. Once I just signed the raw dkim string it worked. Thank you so much for your help!